# Formas de descobrir qual o maior e menor número digitado no input pelo usuário em um for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bem resumidamente estou com uma duvida se há uma forma de fazer este código de outra maneira mais "simples". O código em si já é simples mas queria saber se há outra maneira usando menos linhas ou sem usar a potenciação.

Essa foi a única forma que consegui chegar no resultado desejado:

```
maior = -10 ** 20

menor = -10 ** 20

for c in range(1, 5, +1):
    user_input = float(input('Digite o peso da pessoa Nº{}: '.format(c)))

    if user_input >= maior:
        maior = user_input
    if user_input <= menor:
        menor = user_input

print('O menor peso é {:.2f} e o maior peso é {:.2f}kg'.format(menor, maior))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode iniciar os valores como `None`, ao invés de utilizar valores muito grande ou muito pequeno e, dentro do laço de repetição, verificar se o valor é `None`; se for, atribui o primeiro peso tanto para o menor valor quanto para o maior, porém, se não for `None`, é verificado qual é o menor valor entre o menor valor atual e o novo peso lido, atribuindo o resultado ao menor valor; de igual forma se faz com o maior valor.

O código abaixo irá ler 5 valores do usuário, verificando sempre se são valores numéricos e, quando não for, exibir uma mensagem de erro seguida de uma nova solicitação do valor. Você pode testar isso entrando com alguma letra como peso. Vale lembrar que o padrão de ponto flutuante do Python utiliza ponto como separador decimal e não vírgula como usamos, então a entrada deverá ser algo como `70.5` e não `70,5`.

```
smaller = None
bigest = None

for i in range(5):
    while True:
        try:
            weight = float(input('Entre com o peso da pessoa nº{}'.format(i+1)))
        except ValueError:
            print('Ooops, parece que você digitou um valor não numérico.')
            continue
        break
    smaller = weight if smaller is None else min(smaller, weight)
    bigest = weight if bigest is None else max(bigest, weight)

print('Menor peso: {}'.format(smaller))
print('Maior peso: {}'.format(bigest))
```

Esta solução, diferente da minha anterior, não armazena todos os valores em memória, fazendo a comparação em tempo real, definindo o menor e o maior valores de peso. Perceba que ao final do programa não será possível afirmar quais foram todos os valores entrados pelo usuário e, se isso for necessário, dentro do laço de repetição, o valor de `weight` deverá ser armazenado em uma lista.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson! Sua explicação foi muito boa, sou iniciante e ainda não conhecia essa função min e max. O código ficou bem mais legível e prático.